# How can I eliminate the vertical extra space before and after the proof-environment?

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
Normal theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
Normal proof.
\end{proof}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{rmk}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Some remark.
\begin{proof}
Proof for that remark. %!!!
\end{proof}
\item Other information.
\end{enumerate}
\end{rmk}


\end{document}
```

I want to introduce (best via `newenvironment`) a new kind of proof environment that I can use for remarks and that does not have additional vertical space before and after the proof other than the usual vertical line spacing.

So, the above example looks like

[image]

and I want to get rid of the extra space around the second `Beweis`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Note that you don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. The preferred way to express thanks is through upvoting answers that help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a new environment, duplicating `proof`:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{proof*}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \partopsep=\z@skip \topsep=\z@skip
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

Now you can input the "inner" proof as

```
\begin{proof*}
This is a proof without additional vertical space
\end{proof*}
```