# How to change space around theorem environments?

Tags: spacing, amsthm

Is there a way to change the vertical space before/after theorem environments, without defining a new theorem style? I'm using `amsthm` package to define my new theorem environments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without defining new theorem styles, you can modify the macro that's used by default, which is `\thm@space@setup`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=5cm plus 1cm minus 2cm
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip % or whatever, if you don't want them to be equal
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{thm}
$1+1=2$
\end{thm}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The default value is `\topsep`. You don't need to have the same space above and below the theorem.

Comment: Ha! Perfect!! Thanks so much. Just one question: is `\topsep` used only by this macro? May I change only its value?

Comment: @Sigur `\topsep` is the parameter normally used by list environments (`enumerate`, `itemize` and `description`); I would change neither the spacing around theorems nor `\topsep`, for what it's worth. :)

Comment: @egreg, neither around theorems! Why? Should I use rubber length?

Comment: @Sigur `\topsep` *is* a rubber length. It's default value in the standard classes is 8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt (at 10pt size) or 10pt plus 4pt minus 6pt (at 12pt size). I believe it's a good compromise: not larger than the baseline skip (at least in its natural length), but flexible enough. Theorems already have a header that, together with the spacing, makes them prominent enough.

Comment: OK. I see. You added the rubber space on the answer. Thanks. I'll accept it.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the two parameters locally?

Comment: @Argyll What do you mean?

Comment: Is there a way to modify the before/after environment spacing for a single instance?

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your super fast response as always!!

Comment: @Argyll `\begingroup\setlength{\topsep}{100pt}\begin{thm}...\end{thm}\endgroup`

Comment: But in this case, isn't the preskip and postskip parameters already set to something other than `\topsep`?

Comment: And to clarify, even though I would be curious of how to adjust spacing for theorem environments, I am actually stuck with extra spacing for the `proof` environment. The global solution for `proof` was addressed by you in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49801/how-can-i-eliminate-the-vertical-extra-space-before-and-after-the-proof-environm