# Increase spacing between theorems and before a section starts?

Tags: spacing

The following is the code I am running and I would like to make spaces before a new section starts and space before I write the next line after making section a little bigger. Also is there a way to increse space between theorems, lemmas, corrolaries etc also by just a little.

> ```
> \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
> \usepackage{amsfonts}
> \usepackage{amsthm}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \usepackage{amscd}
> \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
> \usepackage{t1enc}
> \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
> \usepackage{indentfirst}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \usepackage{graphics}
> \usepackage{pict2e}
> \usepackage{epic}
> \numberwithin{equation}{section}
> \usepackage[margin=2.9cm]{geometry}
> \usepackage{epstopdf} 
> \def\numset#1{{\\mathbb #1}}
> \theoremstyle{plain}
> \newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}[section]
> \newtheorem{Lemma}[Th]{Lemma}
> \newtheorem{Cor}[Th]{Corollary}
> \newtheorem{Prop}[Th]{Proposition}
> \theoremstyle{definition}
> \newtheorem{Def}[Th]{Definition}
> \newtheorem{Conj}[Th]{Conjecture}
> \newtheorem{Rem}[Th]{Remark}
> \newtheorem{?}[Th]{Problem}
> \newtheorem{Ex}[Th]{Example}
> \newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
> \newcommand{\Hom}{{\rm{Hom}}}
> \newcommand{\diam}{{\rm{diam}}}
> \newcommand{\ovl}{\overline}
> %\newcommand{\M}{\mathbb{M}}
> \begin{document}
> \title{lipsum}
> \author{John Cena}
> \begin{abstract} Abstract
> \end{abstract}
> \maketitle
> \section{Introduction} In this section
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: Please extend your MWE with some dummy text and an example of theorems.

Comment: Please also clarify what you have in mind for the term "by just a little".

Comment: Off-topic: Any reason for using `latin2` rather than `utf8` as the input encoding option? Aside: `\usepackage{t1enc}` is deprecated; use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead. Still another aside: It's pointless to load both `graphicx` and `graphics`; if this were my document, I'd load only `graphicx`. A third aside: loading the `epstopdf` package should only be necessary if your TeX distribution is at least six years old and hasn't been updated since.

Comment: And, while you're at it fixing up the preamble of your document, you really ought to replace `\newcommand{\Hom}{{\rm{Hom}}}` with `\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}` and replace `\newcommand{\diam}{{\rm{diam}}}` with `\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}`.

Comment: Probably related: [Spacing before and after with \newtheoremstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37472/134144), [How to change space around theorem environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85400/134144) and [Control space between paragraph and example environment - amsthm package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87523/134144)